# I ain't able to run code in cordova-plugin-file

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am quite new in AngularJS and cordova, and are having some little problems to solve simple issues.
I was studying the Cordova-Plugin-File, and aren't able to run it in my AngularJS mobile device application. Could someone help me?

Follow the code, that i take from examples in the web.

javascript:

```
    var logOb = "";
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function (dir) {
        console.log("got main dir", dir);
        dir.getFile("log.txt", { create: true }, function (file) {
            console.log("got the file", file);
            logOb = file;
            writelog("App started");
        });
    });

    function writelog(str) {
        if (!logOb) alert('teste2');
        var log = str + " [" + (new Date()) + "]\n";
        console.log("going to log " + log);
        logOb.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

            fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);

            var blob = new Blob([log], { type: 'text/plain' });
            fileWriter.write(blob);
            console.log("ok, in theory i worked");
        }, fail);
    }
```

Remembering that i already test the plugin and it are working well. I used this tutorial to test it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bizW561ALsY

The commands returned the folders in my cellphone as needed. I just are having problem with the example above, when come in the 'createWriter', command, and are unable to pass from it.

If anyone could help me i would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating.

While i was waiting for a response i found some ways to start to do what i need. First i was able to create the archive .csv.

```
$scope.criaCSV = function () {
    // Create Object

    var items = [
        { name: "Item 1", color: "Green", size: "X-Large" },
        { name: "Item 2", color: "Green", size: "X-Large" },
        { name: "Item 3", color: "Green", size: "X-Large" }];

    // Convert Object to JSON
    var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);

    // Convert JSON to CSV & Display CSV
    ConvertToCSV(jsonObject);
 };

function ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ','
            line += array[i][index];
        }
        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
```

And latter i was able to save a txt archieve in my mobile:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, onError);
}

function onSuccess(fileSystem) {
    alert(fileSystem);
    var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;

    //lets create a file named readme.txt. getFile method actually creates a file and returns a pointer(FileEntry) if it doesn't exist otherwise just returns a pointer to it. It returns the file pointer as callback parameter.
    directoryEntry.getFile("readme.txt", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
        //lets write something into the file
        fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
            alert("This is the text inside readme file");
        }, function (error) {
            alert("Error occurred while writing to file. Error code is: " + error.code);
        });
    }, function (error) {
        alert("Error occurred while getting a pointer to file. Error code is: " + error.code);
    });
}

function onError(evt) {
    alert("Error occurred during request to file system pointer. Error code is: " + evt.code);
}
```

Would someone help me to pass that arch to the code where i save the txt, changing the txt for that arch??

Thank you everyone.